# I should have finished the book by Friday. (past or future?)

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

> I should have finished the book by Friday.

I learned should have pp means past regret.
But the translation means future(prediction).

What's the meaning of the sentence and 'should have pp' also can mean future?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "should have" for past regret "You should have lit the barbeque hours ago"  But this is different.  It is a past-in-the-future construction, meaning "I expect that on Friday (which is in the future) the finishing of the book will be completed"

It is therefore related to "I will have finished the book" but with "should" used instead of "will" to express expectation rather than prediction.